# String matching a pattern and not containing some words

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a regex which match words with a specific pattern (see below) but which doesn't contain one of three specific words

The pattern is

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_~+-]{1,64}
```

and the words I don't want to be contained in the whole word are 'TEST', 'SPECIFIC1' and 'SPECIFIC2'

So far, I found a regex to not match those words:

```
((?!(TEST|SPECIFIC1|SPECIFIC2)).)*
```

but I can't find how to combine those two regex.

For example:

```
TEST            won't match
TES$            won't match
SPECIFIC1       won't match
NON-SPECIFIC2   won't match
SPECIFIC2       won't match
MATCHES         will match
test            will match
```

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: It's easier to match everything you want, and then write a condition.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to have only one regex to do the job

Comment: That's how the code is. It needs a regex

Comment: Usually on StackOverflow it is courtesy to post a repro code to showcase the problem, it makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Just for a regex? ....

Comment: Is it not okay for you to use an if else condition which would reject the match if one of those 3 strings are found?

Comment: @JérèmLeBlond could you post some example input strings, and some examples of output matching that you want?

Comment: I did put examples in my question :) And nope, I can't have an if-else condition

Comment: Yes but even with your examples I have a hard time figuring out what you actually want to do.

Comment: Please post input/ouput examples, don't bother getting into technical details about your regexes. Just tell us what you have (input), and what you want to do with it (output).

Comment: Is this about only matching lines that don't contain any of those 3 words? Or to match each word seperately that's not one of those 3?

Comment: It's about to mach each word that not contain one of those 3 words

Comment: @JérèmLeBlond okay so you actually want to match **words** that do not include one of your three unwanted-words! You should turn your question like that because it's much clearer I think :)

Comment: matching words seperately could be done by using word boundaries : `\b(?!(?:TEST|SPECIFIC1|SPECIFIC2)\b)[a-zA-Z0-9_~+-]{1,64}\b`

Comment: @Jérèm Le Blond: all these comments are asking questions which are much better showcased by writing a simple example of what you want to match and not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you surround the expression with `^` and `$` you can put the negative lookahead together with your character class to accomplish this.

```
^((?!(TEST|SPECIFIC1|SPECIFIC2))[a-zA-Z0-9_~+-]){1,64}$
```

[Here's](https://regex101.com/r/hN9fO5/2) a demonstration. Note that this uses the flags global and multiline so I can have one match per row for demonstration purposes.

Without `^` and `$` the pattern can just be shifted to avoid matching the forbidden strings.

Comment: Thank you but this regex will match words with 'TEST' in it, as testTESTtest

Comment: Updated both regex and link so that it doesn't match *testTESTtest*.